# Visual Studio doesn't recognize local references in the IDE, build works fine

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have really tried to find an answer to this.

All of sudden one of my projects are acting really strange. All references to local stuff in the same project are not resolved bu Visual Studio. All other references to .Net Framework and to my other assemblies works fine.

[image]

ps. I know platform is spelled with one t :D

And as i said it the title. I do not get any errors or anything when i build the project.

- I think this has happened before. Not 100% sure how i fixed it then thou.
- I shall also mention that it seems to work on my second machine with the exact same code.
- I can't remember anything in particular that i did when i noticed it.

**What i've tried**

- Restart both computer and VS.
- Removed /obj and /bin folders
- Tried to fix all warnings and stuff that Visual Studio.

So how does this "design time" resolving works? What files does it use? Is there any log or anything? Anyone have any good ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: You could try deleting/cutting and making a backup of some of the VS project files. They may have been corrupted (random guess).

Comment: This worked! Strange that i couldn't find it when i searched for it. Hopefully this question can help someone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just unloaded, edited the .csproj file and it worked right away. Thanks  Carcigenicate!

Comment: Thats so funny. I'm pretty sure I wasn't sober when I suggested that.